# когда применять DISPLAY

Tags: css, menu, dropdown, display

столкнулся с таким вопросом, какогда и какую функцию нам нужно применять?
всё ещё не ясно, а я так понимаю играет большую роль
например `display:fixed` `display: absolute`
для меня по фнукцианалу очень похожу и понять какая между ними разница мне не удалось

тоже самое и с работай с блочноыми элементами , если мы например хотим сделать выпадающее меню при наведении
почему `display: flex` а не `display: inline` или `display: inline-block`

мне это всё чужду и не понятно, кто подскажет годной ссылкой, или сам сможет всё объяснить,  буду очень рад!
пытался сам всё понять и найти ответы, но не удалось!

Comment: вы грамотно напишите вопрос, может тогда поймем в чем дело,

Comment: Поизучайте-ка чтоли... [тыц](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: https://webref.ru/css/position + https://webref.ru/css/display

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/toggle-visibility-when-hiding-elements/

Comment: `display:fixed;` и `display:absolute` ? что то новенькое